# CakePHP links in same page

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink

I am trying to build a FAQ page, with table of contents on top and answers below it. I would like to click on a question from the table of contents and link on the same page to the corresponding answer. How can I do this in CakePHP, by using `$this->Html->link()` method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use something like this for the link:

```
$this->Html->link($question_title, $this->here . '#question-' . $question_id);
```

and then for later down the page put the answers in something like

```
<div id="question-<?php echo $question_id; ?>"><?php echo $answer_text; ?></div>
```

obviously the vars will be something like `$question['Question']['title']` in cake and the Html->link url could be done with an array like

```
$this->Html->link($question_title, array('action' => 'faq', '#' => 'question-' . $question_id));
```

just as long as the url part before the # exactly matches the current url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was toying with this approach, but wasn't sure if it was the best way.